# UTF-8 charset doesn't work for PHP mail form

Tags: php, email, forms, post

I'm trying to solve the problem of **reading special characters**, (plus I cant get it on one of the Gmail) I get something like this "*×œ×“×•×*" and this "*Ч“Ч•Чђ\"ЧњЧ“Ч•*" sent from my WP blog I've tried all ways which were explained on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but the questions might be specific, which hadn't work for me. I wont use any plugin for that, so my preferred code is here:

```
<?php 
   .....................
        if(!isset($hasError)) {


        $emailTo = 'asdasdasd@mail.ru,  asdasdasd@gmail.com, info@travel-asdasdasd.co.il ' ;
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $comments= $_POST['comments'];
                $dge= $_POST['dge'];
                $tve= $_POST['tve'];
                $weli= $_POST['weli'];
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $ContactName \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments \n\n Subject :$subject \n\n Number: $phone \n\n $dge / $tve /$weli";

        mail($emailTo, ": הודעה" , $body, "Travel-Georgia" );
        ///////////////// 
        // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}    
?>   
    .......

                    <form id="contact-us"  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> .......</form>
```

Comment: You have to set the encoding information for the message, have a look at the [mail function in PHP.net](http://my1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) there you will find very useful information, specially on the comments area.

Comment: Also, make sure you Form submits UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode your E-Mail contents using proper E-Mail encoding methods before they show up correctly in E-Mails.

If I were you, I would use [wp_mail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function inside WordPress to send the E-Mails. I don't know if it does all the required encodings though.

Another alternative is to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send the E-Mails. It certainly takes care of all the encoding and other duties needed to send properly encoded E-Mail.